# Concatenate fields on Odoo v9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm trying to concatenate  3 fields to form a internal code and display it in the views:

I have 3 models:

- Category (size=2)
- Product  (size=4)
- Serie    (size=3)

And I want to display it in the form like this

Product Code: CAT-PROD-001

I don't know if i have to use a computed field or if exist anoter way to do this, because I was doing test with computed fields but can't reach the desired output.

**Edit:**

Now I'm trying to use a computed field with a onchange function to generate the value on the field

**MODEL**

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from openerp import models,fields,api
class exec_modl(models.Model):
        _name           =   "exec.modl"
        _rec_name       =   "exec_desc"
        exec_code       =   fields.Char('Identificador',required=True,size=3)
        exec_desc       =   fields.Char('Descripción',required=True)
        cour_exec       =   fields.Many2one('cour.modl')
        proc_exec       =   fields.Many2one('enro.modl')
        inte_code       =   fields.Char(compute='_onchange_proc')
```

**FUNCTION**

```
  @api.onchange('proc_exec')
    def _onchange_proc(self):
        cate    =   "XX"
        cour    =   "XXXX"
        exet    =   "XXX"
        output  =   cate+"-"+cour+"-"+exet
        return output
```

I'm just trying with plain values just to know how to send it to the field.

**EDIT 2:**

Using the answer from @Charif I can print the static strings on the form, but the next milestome I'm trying to reach is getting the codes (external models fields) to crate that **inte_code**

ex: From the model cour.modl I want to get the value from the field **cour_code(internal_id for course)** corresponding to the cour_exec field on the first model (the cour_exec field have the description of the course from cour.modl model)

```
@api.depends('proc_exec')
        def _onchange_proc(self):
            cate    =   "XX"
            cour    =   self.env['cour.modl'].search([['cour_desc','=',self.cour_exec]])
            exet    =   "XXX"
            output  =   cate+"-"+cour+"-"+exet
            self.inte_code = output
```

E        @api.depends('inte_code')
        def _onchange_proc(self):
            cate    =   "XX"
            # first domain use tuple not list
            cour_result    =   self.env['cour.modl'].search([('id','=',exec_modl.cour_exec)]).cour_code
            cour = "" # empty string because you cannot contcatenate None or False with a string value
            #if  cour_result : 
            #    cour = ",".join(crse_code for crse_code in cour_result.ids)
            #else :
            #    print "result of search is empty check you domain"
            exet    =   "XXX"
            output  =   cate+"-"+cour+"-"+exet+"-"+cour_result
            self.inte_code = output

**EDIT 3**

I've been trying to usse the search mode calling other model values but I have the console output :

***Can't adapt type 'Many2One'*** , seems im trying to compare 2 different type of fields, the types can be parsed on odoo ? or I'm using a wrong syntax for search method?

```
   @api.depends('inte_code')
    def _onchange_proc(self):
        cate    =   "XX"
        # first domain use tuple not list
        cour_result    = self.env['cour.modl'].search([('id','=',exec_modl.cour_exec)]).cour_code

        exet    =   "XXX"
        output  =   cate+"-"+cour+"-"+exet+"-"+cour_result
        self.inte_code = output
```

**EDIT 4 : ANSWER**
***Finally I've reach the desired output!*** using the following code:

```
@api.depends('inte_code')
        def _onchange_proc(self):
            cate_result    = self.cate_exec
            proc_result    =    self.env['enro.modl'].search([('id','=',str(self.proc_exec.id))]).enro_code
            cour_result    =    self.env['cour.modl'].search([('id','=',str(self.cour_exec.id))]).cour_code
            output  =   str(proc_result)+"-"+str(cate_result)+"-"+str(cour_result)+"-"+self.exec_code
            self.inte_code = output
```

Additionaly I've added a related field for add the course category to the final output.

```
cate_exec       =   fields.Char(related='cour_exec.cour_cate.cate_code')
```

> Now the output have this structure:
>
> INTERNAL_PROC_ID-CAT_COURSE-COURSE-EXECUTION_CODE
>
> EX: xxxxxxxx-xx-xxxx-xxx

Comment: Is one of this field a compute field if not than use compute field put your code that you tried and didn't work as you wanted

Comment: I've added some code of my local tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First in compute field use api.depends not onchange :
2. Second the compute function don't return anything but it passes the record on the self variable so all you have to do is assign the value to the computed field.

```py
@api.depends('proc_exec')
def _onchange_proc(self):
    # compute the value 
    # ... 
    # Than assign it to the field
    self.computed_field =   computed_value
```

one of the thing that i recommand to do is to loop the self because it's recordSet so if the self contains more than one record this previous code will raise signlton error 
 so you can do this :

```py
# compute the value here if it's the same for every record in self
for rec in self :
     # compute the value here it depends on the value of the record 
     rec.compute_field = computeValue
```

or use `api.one` with `api.depends`

```py
@api.one
@api.depends('field1', 'field2', ...)
```

EDITS:

```py
    @api.depends('proc_exec')
    def _onchange_proc(self):
        cate    =   "XX"
        # first domain use tuple not list
        cour_result    =   self.env['cour.modl'].search([('cour_desc','=',self.cour_exec)])
        cour = "" # empty string because you cannot contcatenate None or False with a string value
        if cour_result : 
            cour = ",".join(id for id in cour_result.ids)
        else :
            print "result of search is empty check you domain"
        exet    =   "XXX"
        output  =   cate+"-"+cour+"-"+exet
        self.inte_code = output
```

try this code i think the result of search is a recordSet so you can get the list of ids by name_of_record_set.ids  than create a string from the list of ids to concatenate it try and let me know if there is an error because i'm using work PC i don't have odoo on my hand ^^

Comment: api.depends act like on change also but more complex because the field will be recomputed if one of the field that depends on them to compute the value has changed not on the view but also in the database so if you execute write method on some method that change the value of one of the field this method is called the field is recomputed even if it's not on the view

Comment: It works fine to print static data, but now im trying to "import" the ids from another modules for cate, cour, and exet, ill add the code in the main post.

Comment: added more code to the main post, I'm using the search method but seems i have to create a new one to get the ids from an external model.

Comment: I've tryed the code but the console ouput says "invalid key"  i'm now trying with other code (added to main post)

Answer (score 1):

You can create new wizard.

From wizard you can generate Internal Reference.

```py
class create_internal_reference(models.TransientModel):

    _name="create.internal.reference"

    @api.multi
    def create_internal_reference(self):
        product_obj=self.env['product.product']
        active_ids=self._context.get('active_ids')
        if active_ids:
            products=product_obj.browse(active_ids)
            products.generate_new_internal_reference()            
        return True
```

Create View & act_window

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="create_internal_reference_1">
    <field name="name">Create Internal Reference</field>
    <field name="model">create.internal.reference</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Create Internal Reference">
            <footer>
                <button name="create_internal_reference" string="Generate Internal Reference" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>                  
                <button string="Cancel" class="oe_link" special="cancel" />
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

<act_window name="Generate Internal Reference" res_model="create.internal.reference"
src_model="product.product" view_mode="form" view_type="form"
target="new" multi="True" key2="client_action_multi"
id="action_create_internal_reference"
view_id="create_internal_reference_1"/>
```

```py
class product_product(models.Model):

   _inherit='product.product'

    @api.multi  
    def generate_new_internal_reference(self):    
        for product in self:
            if not product.internal_reference:
                product.internal_reference='%s-%s-%s'%(str(product.categ_id.name)[:2],str(product.name)[:4],third_field[:3])
```

From product.product under more button you can access this wizard and generate internal reference.

This may help you.

Comment: Why so complicated and not just using a computed field?

Comment: You can use Compute field as well, but In Compute field every time  system will  automatic generate internal reference.let's say if you change product name then system will change internal reference as well. this is not good solution

Comment: Yes, if it is related to the product name, i'm with you. But if it depends on 3 fields (or relations) which aren't changed that often, i would prefer a stored computed field.

Comment: Im trying to use a stored computed field because my courses (products from a custom model) are created just one time and rarely modified after implemented. thanks for your example anyways ill use it as guidelines to reach my output